# Convert flattened 1 dimensional indices to 2 dimensional indices

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested-lists, indices

Say I have a list of lists, e.g:

```
x = [[0,1,2,3],[4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]]
```

And I have the 'flat' indices of the elements I wish to target, i.e, the indices of the elements I want to select from the list if it were flattened into a 1d list:

```
flattened_indices = [0,1,4,9]

                  # #     #         #
flattened_list = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

How do I convert the 1.d. indices into 2.d. indices that would allow me to recover the elements from the original nested list? I.e. in this example:

```
2d_indices = [(0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (2,3)]
```

Comment: wouldn't it be easier if you flatten the list and extract the elements rather than converting the indices into 2D?

Comment: You can convert the indices to 2-d indices by looking at the length of the lists and doing some simple math. Did you try that?

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar the actual problem is a little more complicated than the toy model I've used, with each 'sublist' actually being a variable length sublist of sublists. As such, flattening the lists doesn't make sense when there might be 3 lists in the first element, but only 2 in the second, and you would also have the benefit of being able to reuse the indices for each element as opposed to flattening multiple times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a way to do that:

```py
from bisect import bisect
import itertools

# Accumulated sum of list lengths
def len_cumsum(x):
    return list(itertools.accumulate(map(len, x)))

# Find 2D index from accumulated list of lengths
def find_2d_idx(c, idx):
    i1 = bisect(c, idx)
    i2 = (idx - c[i1 - 1]) if i1 > 0 else idx
    return (i1, i2)
```

```py
# Test
x = [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
indices = [0, 4, 9]
flattened_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
c = len_cumsum(x)
idx_2d = [find_2d_idx(c, i) for i in indices]

print(idx_2d)
>>> [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 3)]

print([x[i1][i2] for i1, i2 in idx_2d])
>>> [0, 4, 9]
```

If you have many "flat" indices, this is more effective than iterating the nested list for each index.

Comment: I did not test it, might be an off-by-one-error somewhere, don't know. The idea is sound. You could use `list(itertools.accumulate(map(len, x)))` instead of that `len_cumsum` function, though.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could put these index pairs in a dict, then just reference the dict from `indices` at the end and create a new list:

```
x = [[0,1,2,3],[4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]]

indices = [0,4,9]

idx_map = {x: (i, j) for i, l in enumerate(x) for j, x in enumerate(l)}

result = [idx_map[x] for x in indices]
print(result)
```

Which results in:

```
[(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 3)]
```

But this is not optimal since its quadratic runtime to create `idx_map`. [@jdehesa's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56144854/convert-1-dimensional-indices-to-2-dimensional-indices/56145073#56145073) solution using bisect is much more optimal.

Comment: This assumes that `x` contains the natural numbers in increasing order (i.e. `xx[i] == i` if `xx` is the flattened list) and doesn't work for anything else, like `x = [['a','a','a','a'],['a','a'],['a','a','a','a','a']]`.